# Finding the cell reference of a "Cells.Find" function

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the code below to find a value the user has searched for ("strFindWhat") which is entered into a cell and a button is then pressed to trigger this sub. The system conatains a long list of data and the user will be searching for say a product number so that they can quickly see the corresponding batch no.

```
Cells.Find(What:=strFindWhat, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False).Select
```

What I want to do is find the refrence to the cell that is found by this code. So that I can change the colour or maybe row of the found cell in order to highlight the data they need so they can see it clearer.
I have tried the obvious by making the whole function equal a variable:

```
foundCell = Cells.Find(What:=strFindWhat, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False).Select
```

The value of "foundCell" always comes out as blank and I was hoping someone knows of a way to find the reference to the found cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to find the address you could do sth like that

```
Dim foundCell As Range
    Set foundCell = Cells.Find(What:=strFindWhat, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
             :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                        False)

    If Not (foundCell Is Nothing) Then
        Debug.Print foundCell.Address
    End If
```

Comment: This works perfectly thanks. instead of the debug.print I've made it so it equals a variable "foundAddress" to make it easier to call upon. So the address found will always be in the form $X$Y. Is there a way of making this equal just XY? So that i can then use this to change the cell colour: range("foundAddress")interior.color etc...

Comment: But you do not need that as you have foundCell which is a range and you could write `foundCell.interior.color ...`

Comment: I tried that originally but the value of foundCell without .address isn't the cell address, it's the same as the value of strFindWhat. eg. It will show 1653 instead of $A$5. Thats why i made the foundAddress variable as it will always only be the address

Comment: I do not really understand. foundCell is a range and it cannot be the same as strFindWhat only foundCell.value.

Comment: If i use    foundCell.interior.color.....     it doesnt change the colour of the cell found/ the cell that's in foundCell.address. It changes the cell that the user inputs to search for. So    strFindWhat = Sheet5.Range("E1").value     and foundCell changes E1. If that makes sense...

Comment: No, does not really make sense for me. If I try my code and add `foundCell.Interior.Color = vbRed` then the cell where strFindWhat is contained will be colored red.