# How to get VBA code to check if cell value matches column heading and return value from another cell in the same row?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, range

I've searched all over and can't seem to get this piece working.

I have 2 worksheets.

Sheet 1 contains the quiz question numbers and then the score for each corresponding q#.

Sheet 2 contains each q# as column headings and I'd like for the VBA code to grab the score from the q# that corresponds to the right heading.

For ex:

Sheet 1

```
Question#      Score 
1               100
2                90
3                75
4                95
```

Sheet 2

```
Q1    Q2    Q3   Q4 
100   90    75   95
```

The column headings in Sheet 2 can be changed to simply say "1", "2", etc so there can be an exact match if that makes it easier.

I found and played with this code but it copies the entire column if it finds a match which doesnt work:

```
Sub CopyDataDynamically()
Dim lr As Long, num As Long
Dim rng As Range
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("a2")
num = Range("b2").Value
If num = 1 Then
    Range("B2:B" & lr).Copy
    rng.Offset(0, num - 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change the heading and use VLOOKUP()

Comment: If it's a one-time thing copy the table and `paste special -> transpose` may do the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always find it good practice to `Dim` your `Workbook` and `Worksheet`. If you decide to expand you're already set.

The following code will essentially transpose the data set, no matter how many questions.

```
Sub test()


Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wks_1 As Worksheet
Dim wks_2 As Worksheet

    Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
    Set wks_1 = wbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wks_2 = wbk.Sheets("Sheet2")

    LastRow = wks_1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        wks_1.Cells(i, 1).Copy wks_2.Cells(1, i)
        wks_1.Cells(i, 2).Copy wks_2.Cells(2, i)
    Next i


End Sub
```

It will copy the headers also.

Firstly I want to know where the last row is, hence the `LastRow` code. Then we simply loop through all rows and transpose the data set.

The reference `.Cells` in line `wks_1.Cells(i, 1).Copy wks_2.Cells(1, i)` always references `Row` then `Col`.

Let me know how you go.

Comment: thank you for the code above! the problem i'm having is that this works great if all the columns line up. however, the example i provided was simplified. all the columns/data points aren't always lined up perfectly.

is there a way to get it to match the cell's content to the column heading, and if true, return that cell's value?

Comment: Thanks for the tick as it answers your question. much appreciated. Anything is possible. May I suggest starting a new question stating what you are after. Also give this link a read and see if you can answer your own question. If not I'd be more than happy to help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52113901/finding-the-cell-reference-of-a-cells-find-function